# PHPMailer attachment pathfile name not displaying for attachment

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

PHPMailer attachment issue:

When I do a var_dump($_FILES), it displays all the correct content within the array, and also moves the uploaded file to my attachments folder, so this part works perfectly in my form. I added the form attribute enctype="multipart/form-data" to encode the form data over the server.

So, my issue is trying to display the $_files['attachment'] pathfile name to the page using echo $file after the form submitted. This is not working and I dont know why?

To give a background of my file structure:

1. main directory folder: mailer-for-php
2. folder within: attachments
3. folder within: images
4. directory folder within: vendor (with associated composer files and PHPMailer
5. sendmail-v2.php

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];

//var_dump($_FILES);

if (isset($_FILES['attachment']['name']) && $_FILES['attachment']['name'] !="") {
  $file = "attachments/" . basename($_FILES['attachment']['name']);
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], $file);
} else{
  $file = " ";

echo $file;
}
} // end of post submit

?>
```

HTML form code:

```
<form method="post" action="sendmail-v2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="name">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" placeholder="subject">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="email">

          <textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="enter message here" rows="3"></textarea>

          <input type="file" name="attachment" class="file-input form-control d-block mb-4" id="attachment-file">

          <!-- display pathfile selected to user -->
           <!-- <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById('attachment-file').onchange = function () {
              alert('Selected file: ' + this.value);
            };
          </script> -->

          <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="send email">
      </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting echo in your else statement. Put it outside else like this

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$name = $_POST['name'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

//var_dump($_FILES);

if (isset($_FILES['attachment']['name']) && $_FILES['attachment']['name'] !="") {
$file = "attachments/" . basename($_FILES['attachment']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], $file);
} else{
$file = " ";
}
echo $file;

} // end of post submit

?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Ah, your the best, thanks for seeing that. I am obviously new to PHP, much appreciated.

Comment: Glad it helped. Accept it as answer so that it help others.

Comment: I have another PHPMailer issue, if you would like to help me, here is the link.[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46901711/phpmailer-not-sending-at-all]